# DataGridView null value

Tags: datagridview

DataGridView:  I have 3 numeric columns.  I want to be able to delete an entry in these columns so that the cell in that column resets to a null value.  As it stands now, I get a parsing, commit error.

This occurs after I edit the datagridview columns formatting to Numeric, N4

If I enter a number in one of the columns, 145.49 for instance, everything works fine. However, if I then want to delete the number, 145.49, and have no number in the cell I get the parsing error. How do I overcome the error? I want to return the cell to it's null state. Thanks – Bruce

How do I accomplish this?  In Visual Basic, please.

Comment: What code have you written so far to accomplish this, can you post it please?

Comment: You question is extremely vague. To avoid possible down votes and to get a good answer you may want to revise your question to be more specific as to what problem you are having. Showing what you have tried is expected. You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) …  AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If I enter a number in one of the columns, 145.49 for instance, everything works fine.  However, if I then want to delete the number, 145.49, and have no number in the cell I get the parsing error.  How do I overcome the error?  I want to return the cell to it's null state.  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the code is parsing the cell’s value somewhere and since the cell is empty the parse is obviously failing. Check for empty values before you parse the number so it does not fail. Since there is no code to show how this parsing is done, it will be difficult to say where the problem is.